# Как преобразовать текст из файла в словарь? В каждой строчке текста есть символ "|". То что перед ним должно быть ключом, после - значением

Tags: python, файлы, словари

В файле содержится текст:

**Foundation|Asimov, Isaac**

**Foundation and Empire|Asimov, Isaac**

**Second Foundation|Asimov, Isaac**

Нужно привести это к виду:

```
{'Foundation': 'Asimov, Isaac', 'Foundation and Empire': 'Asimov, Isaac', 'Second Foundation': 'Asimov, Isaac'}
```

Пробовал так:

```
with open(f'{filename}', 'r') as s:
        data = s.read()
        for i in data:
            if '|' in i:
                result = dict(enumerate(data.split()))
                return result
```

но получается только:

```
{0: 'Foundation|Asimov, Isaac', 1: 'Foundation and Empire|Asimov, Isaac', 2: 'Second Foundation|Asimov, Isaac', 3: 'Dune|Herbert, Frank'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

конструктор `dict()` вы использовали немного не так, попробуйте примерно вот так:

```
with open(f'{filename}', 'r') as s:
    data = s.read().split('\n')

result = dict((i.split('|')) for i in data)
```

для `data = ['Foundation|Asimov, Isaac', 'Foundation and Empire|Asimov, Isaac', 'Second Foundation|Asimov, Isaac']` получаем результат:

```
{'Foundation': 'Asimov, Isaac',
 'Foundation and Empire': 'Asimov, Isaac',
 'Second Foundation': 'Asimov, Isaac'}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result = {}    
with open(f'{filename}', 'r') as s:
    data = s.readlines() # читаем содержание файла в список
    for line in data:
        elements = line.split("|") # делим строку по "|" на части и сохраняем в список
        result[elements[0]] = elements[1] # добавляем в словарь
```

Comment: Я только учусь, и делаю ошибки. Спасибо за ваш ответ и комментарий, в будущем возьму на заметку.